# Error con react native

Tags: react-native

todo funcionaba bien hasta que intente implementar

```
react-native-router-flux'
```

utilice el comando para instarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
npm i react-native-router-flux
```

y mi archivo de rutas quedo de tal forma:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Stack, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Sigup from './pages/Signup';

export default class Routes extends Component<{}>{

    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Stack key='root'>
                    <Scene key='login' component={Login} title='Login'/>
                    <Scene key='registrer' component={Sigup} title='Registrer'/>                    
                </Stack>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

me manda el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo visto estás usando ¿dobles dependencias? con yarn y npm, además, te aconsejo que cuando instales un paquete lo hagas con --save para que lo guardes en el package.json, como te dice el mismo error corre yarn y npm install

Comment: corro npm install pero no hace nada. Termina de ejecutarse pero no resuelve nada

Comment: @ManuelMorales ha resuelto el problema?

Comment: reiniciando el emulador me funciono!

Answer (score 0):

prueba haciendo esto `react-native unlink react-native-router-flux && react-native link react-native-router-flux`, esto siempre me soluciona cuando algún componente no me carga.

Comment: _Command `unlink` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project._

Comment: _react-native init_ ¿Como puedo recuperar los módulos si los elimino?

Comment: `npm install`  o `yarn install` , otra cosa, ya intentaste reiniciar el serve?